# Which Gmail Notifier do you use?

Tags: software-recommendation, gmail

There are plenty of them.

Which one would you recommend?

Is there one which notifies about unread buzz posts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

gm-notify : https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gm-notify

It integrates best for notifying, but not for managing the e-mail straight from it (like checkgmail) or describing the content of the e-mail after the notification.

[image: gm-notify]

Comment: It's a memory hog though (currently using 22MB - for just sitting in the messages indicator).

Comment: Although a memory hog, I certainly appreciate gm-notify's simplicity and reliability. checkgmail is full of bugs and doesn't even work on Natty. A worthy alternative is running Thunderbird all of the time and having it pop up its notifications when new mail comes in.

Comment: No buzz notifications?

Comment: This one works very nice.

Answer (score 1):

This is the one I use and works perfect: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/gm-notify/

There is also this one which I tried and also works good (Include gmail, reader, etc..): http://sourceforge.net/projects/googsystray/

So you have a choice of a pop balloon like or a small icon in tray that notifies you.

Answer (score 0):

I use `WebMail Notifier` - it's a firefox extension. When new mail comes (and you have firefox turned on) - small message pops-up at the bottom rigth corner of the screen. You can click that message - and it drives you do gmail in a new tab.

Also it has a small notifier - which you can place in a firefox toolbar - and it shows wither you have new mails.